# How to allow a "standard user" (no sudo) make IP config changes without requiring admin password

Tags: password, users, ifconfig

Anyone know if it is possible to have a "Standard User" account make IP changes (via GUI or terminal) without requiring the admin (sudo) password?

I want the user to be able to change interface from and to DHCP + set a static config (IP,mask, DG, DNS).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to be careful with this (especially if you specify the "NOPASSWD:" option.

access the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line to the sudoer file:

```
user ALL = (root) {path/to/command}
```

I believe you could use this to specify a user (or users) that could run a specific command.

Source - http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/127273-allow-user-use-specific-root-command.html

Full Disclosure - I have used this before (for other purposes). But I haven't tried to specify multiple users, or commands dealing with making changes to network interfaces.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change network settings as a standard user. Yet you have to use sudo. Sorry. Just ask to be added to sudoers.

Comment: This answer would benefit from citing supporting documentation, or a more detailed explanation, for how you are sure this is not possible. Right now it's unclear if you are really sure this cannot be done, or if you're just expressing your belief that it cannot.

Answer (score -2):

In Windows OS, we can give the privilege to a standard user for making TCP/IP configuration changes, such as, changing IP configuration from DHCP to Manual, also changing IP, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway, DNS severs, etc. The user has to be added in "Network Configuration Operators" groups.

The user can also disable/enable/repair Network Connections.

1. Start>Run>CMD>COMPMGMT.MSC
2. System Tools>Local Users and Groups>Groups
3. Double click "Network Configuration Operators" and click on "Add".
4. Specify the user who needs IP configuration change rights.

Comment: This is useful information for Windows users, but this question (and indeed, this whole site) is about Ubuntu. It would be better for you to post this information on a Windows or general computing site. **It doesn't answer the question that was asked here (which is about how to do this in Ubuntu).**